# Question on Django queryset searching across multiple models and fields

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following models within my Django code.

```
class Card(models.Model):
    card_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    geography_choices = [('Africa', 'Africa'), ('Asia', 'Asia'), ('Australia', 'Australia'), ('Europe', 'Europe'), ('North America', 'North America'), ('South America', 'South America')]
    geography = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=geography_choices, default='North America')

    type_choices = [('Creature', 'Creature'), ('Spell', 'Spell'), ('New Type', 'New Type'),('Undecided', 'Undecided')]
    card_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=type_choices, default='Creature')


class Article(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    body = models.TextField()

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    )

    entry_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-entry_date_time']

    score_choices = [(-5,'-5'), (-4, '-4'), (-3,'-3'), (-2, '-2'), (-1,'-1'), (0,'0'),
    (1,'1'), (2,'2'), (3,'3'), (4,'4'), (5,'5')]
    score = models.FloatField(choices=score_choices, default=0)


    read_through_choices = [(-1, 'Competitive'), (0, 'No Effect'), (1, 'Industry-Wide')]
    read_through = models.IntegerField(choices=read_through_choices, default=0)


    cardvar = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I also had the following function as a query within my views as a search feature:

```
def get_queryset(self): #new 
        query =self.request.GET.get('q')
        results = Article.objects.filter(
            Q(cardvar__card_name__iexact=query)
        ).order_by('cardvar', '-entry_date_time')
        return results
```

However, this search function only returns articles whose "card topic" is specifically the one searched. What I would like to do is by searching for a card name (cardvar) to return not only articles with that cardvar Foreignkey but ALSO articles which a) have the same card_type as card_var, as well as b) have an Article score not equal to zero. I would like to return these results (i.e. Articles) by searching for a specific card_name. I hope this is clear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you should first make a query and get the `card_type` of the searched `card_name` and then use it in your query it would be something like this:

```py
    query =self.request.GET.get('q')
    card_dict = Card.objects.values('card_type').get(card_name=query)
    results = Article.objects.filter(
        Q(cardvar__card_name__iexact=query) | (Q(cardvar__card_type=card_dict['card_type'] & ~Q(score=0))
    ).order_by('cardvar', '-entry_date_time')
```

Comment: Thank you! Currently I have this above my get_queryset function:  model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_list'
    template_name = 'search_results.html' Which "imports" the Article model. How do I get the view to also "know" to use the Card model?

Comment: no the `model = Article` is for this view class which i presume is a `ListView` it does not have anything to do with importing Article model. if card and article model is in the same file ,  at the beginning of your `views.py` file search for importing of Article and add `Card` next to it